# How to do OTP Authentication in Flutter without using Firebase?

Tags: flutter, authorization, two-factor-authentication

I have searched many websites and I didn't find a way to implement phone authentication in Flutter without using Firebase. Can anyone tell me how to this?

Comment: What are you looking to verify? The phone number of the current device? Or that the user has the possession factor (see Factors in https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-factor_authentication)? Depending on what you are looking to verify there may be a few options.

Comment: I want to verify the phone number provided by a user using https://msg91.com/ api